# "Passing" the implementation of an abstract method through to subclass further down in Python?

Tags: python, pylint

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better way to phrase the title!

Basically, I want an abstract base class, then a sub-class of that which doesn't implement the abstract method, then a sub-class of *that*, which *does* implement the method. It's probably easier with an example:

```
import abc
class A(abc.ABC):
  def __init__(self, some_var):
    self.some_var = some_var

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def some_method(self):
    pass

class B(A):
  def some_b_method(self):
    print("Hello")

class C(B):
  def some_method(self):
    self.some_b_method()
    print(self.some_var)

c = C('world')
c.some_method()
```

This is how I would expect it to work, but for the **B** class above Pylint reports [warning 0223](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0223).

Pylint doesn't give me any problems if I modify the **B** class to include the following, but the duplication of code seems wrong:

```
@abc.abstractmethod
def some_method(self):
  pass
```

Is there a "correct" way? I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be defining an abstract base class with an abstract method if you are *immediately* going to not implement that method.  Your better bet is to define the ABC without the abstract method, and also define a mixin class that contains the method.  You can subclass `class B` from `class A`, and then subclass `class C` from `class B` and the mixin.

```
import abc
class A(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, some_var):
        self.some_var = some_var

class MixinA(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def some_b_method(self):
        print("Hello")

class C(B, MixinA):
    def some_method(self):
        self.some_b_method()
        print(self.some_var)

c = C('world')
c.some_method()

# returns:
Hello
world

# list the methods:
[m for m in dir(c) if not m.startswith('_')]
# returns:
['some_b_method', 'some_method', 'some_var']
```

Answer (score 0):

The *"correct"* way is that `class B` does not inherit from `abstract class A`; if it does, `B` must implement all `abstract methods` of `A`

Another approach it to have `class C` inherit from both `class A`, and `class B`, with `B` independent of `A`:

```
import abc
class A(abc.ABC):
  def __init__(self, some_var):
    self.some_var = some_var

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def some_method(self):
    pass

class B():
  def some_b_method(self):
    print("Hello")

class C(A, B):
  def some_method(self):
    self.some_b_method()
    print(self.some_var)

c = C('world')
c.some_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Python can do this: just raise `NotImplementedError` in the method definition in the intermediate class.

```
class BaseClass :

    def method(...) :
        ... actually do something ...
    #end method

#end BaseClass

class Subclass(BaseClass) :

    def method(...) :
        raise NotImplementedError
    #end method

    ...

#end Subclass

class SubSubclass(Subclass) :

    def method(...) :
        ... actually do something else ...
    #end method

#end SubSubclass
```

Does that sound like what you’re looking for?

Comment: This seems like a decent alternative to `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be against some people's style to have an inheritance hierarchy of abstract classes, I think your current code is fine. You don't need to change anything if you don't want to.

Pylint is giving you a warning, since you're doing something that in some situations might be an error, but in others may be OK. If you expected `B` to be a concrete class, inheriting an abstract method from `A` without overriding it would be a problem. But if you expect `B` to be abstract just like `A`, then it's find for it to not override the abstract method it inherited.

So you can either just ignore the warning from Pylint, or suppress the warning by putting a comment `# pylint: disable=W0223` in your file. Depending on exactly where the comment is put, I believe it can either disable the warning for the just one specific class or for the whole module.